# Define $\|\cdot\| \colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ by $\|a\| =\sum 2^n |a_n| $, then choose the correct option

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Define  $\|\cdot\|\colon V  \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ by $\|a\| = \sum 2^n |a_n|  $,  where  $V$ denotes the vector space  of all sequences  $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dotsc)$ of real numbers such that $\sum 2^n |a_n|  $ converges.

Which of the following are true?

1) $V$ contains only the sequence $(0,0,\dotsc)$

2) $V$ is finite dimensional

3) $V$ has a countable linear basis

4) $V$ is a complete normed space

My answer:  it is already given that $\sum 2^n |a_n|  $ converges. That  means $V$ contain contains  only the sequence $(0,0,\dotsc)$ so option 1) is correct.

Option 2  is  incorrect because  $\mathbb{R}$ is  uncountable, as continuous image of uncountable  is  uncountable.

I'm confused  about option 3 and option 4.

Please help me.

Any hints/solution will be  appreciated.

Comment: Hints: 1, 2 and 3 are incorrect.

Comment: Why is 1) correct? It means $dim V=0$

Comment: how ?? im not getting @egreg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 is incorrect, because all sequences having only finitely many nonzero entries belong to $V$. This also easily shows that 2 is incorrect.

Also option 3 is incorrect, because a complete normed vector space cannot have a countably infinite basis (either finite or uncountable).

On the other hand, option 4 is correct, because…

Comment: @ egreg ..can u little more elaborate,,,why  not infinitely  many non zero entries  belong to V??

Comment: Messi, can you show us some non trivial elements of $V$?

Comment: $(1,0,0,\cdots)$ is a non-zero element of $V.$ As is $(1,a,a^2,a^3,\cdots)$ when $|a|<1/2$

Comment: @egreg can space have Shauder basis?

Comment: @FailedtobeaMathematician This space definitely has one.

Comment: How do I show that?

Comment: Will $e_1,e_2,...,$ be shauder basis?

Comment: @FailedtobeaMathematician Yes.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The map $\ell^1 \to V$ given by $$(x_n)_n \mapsto \left(\frac{x_n}{2^n}\right)_n$$
 is an isometric isomorphism.

Therefore just check what properties hold for $\ell^1$ (only option $4$).